# Running only the tests of a specific file

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm

I have two files with unit tests, with the tests on the second file extending and overriding some of the tests on the first file.

Illustrating with a very simplified example. There's `tests1.py`:

```
import unittest

class A(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "setup stuff A"

    def test_stuff(self):
        print "test stuff A"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And `tests2.py`:

```
import unittest
from tests1 import A

class B(A):
    def setUp(self):
        print "setup stuff B"

    def test_stuff(self):
        print "test stuff B"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I want to be able to run each file on its own, or run the whole set of files in one batch. And I don't want to manually create different suites in which I have to manually specify the set of tests to run...

However... With the example above, when I run the `python tests2.py`, the tests of `tests1.py` are also ran! And when I run them all in a batch, they are ran twice. I understand this happens because I'm importing `A` from `tests2.py`. How can I avoid this? Is there a best practice for this that I should be following?

I am actually running the tests from PyCharm, but I suppose that may not be relevant, as I can reproduce the same issue running the tests from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Split out the common code into another class which does not inherit from `unittest.TestCase`:

```
class Parent(object):
    pass # common stuff goes here

class A(Parent, unittest.TestCase):
    pass # A stuff here

class B(Parent, unittest.TestCase):
    pass # B stuff here
```

Comment: Doable, even if not ideal... as there will be a new ``Parent`` class for each pair of classes ``A`` and ``B``. I need share test implementation for a few dozens of cases, so there will be lots of new classes

Comment: I've edited your example so that in ``A`` and ``B`` we can override the setUp() defined in ``Parent``. Otherwise, the TestCase.setUp() is invoked when calling super(), instead of the intended Parent.setUp()